# How to set Big Picture Image and Banner in Steam

Tags: steam

In the new updated Steam Library; I am able to add a 'Non-Steam Game', set a custom icon to it and set ***'Custom Artwork'*** for it.

When I set a custom icon; I use `'.ico'` files and that works fine.

When I set ***'Custom Artwork'***; I use `'.png'` files `300px by 450px` (Portrait) and that works fine in the normal library.

But when I go to ***Steam Big Picture***; I see only generic steam landscape cover images or the games' original icon. (Not the custom `'.ico'` I set.)

How can I set custom landscape cover images in ***Steam Big Picture*** for my 'Non-Steam Games'?

Also I've found this site: [Steam Banners](https://steambanners.booru.org/)

...and was wondering how to set the banner image after selecting a game in my library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The dynamic background images of games in Big Picture mode are loaded dynamically. As with the regular mode, **it will look for these in your 'Screenshots' folder as well**.
  As an example, I've added Conarium to Steam as a custom game, and made a few screenshots.
  As you can see, they show up as background:

  [image: Custom background images for custom games in Steam Big Picture]

  The files themselves are somewhat hard to find, but I found them here:

  [image: screenshot in Windows 10 of location of screenshots of custom game in Steam]

  You can copy additional images to this folder to use as background images of your custom game in Big Picture mode.

---

- **You can set the custom banner image using Big Picture Mode**:

  - Navigate to the game
  - Select 'Manage Shortcut'
  - Select 'Change Icon...'

  [image: Setting custom banner icon in Steam Big Picture]

  Alternatively, you can add a custom banner image manually, by navigating to your Steam installation folder, to *\userdata*, to the (only) folder with a unique numerical value as a name, and then *\config\grid*,  (e.g. "*C:\Program Files\Steam\userdata\1234567\config\grid*").
  Here, Steam keeps your custom library images. If you've already set a custom image, it should be here, named with an identifier number and either '*_header*', '*_hero*', '*_logo*', or '*p*' (for portrait) appended.
  '*_header*' is the banner image.
  Copy an image to this folder, rename it using the same ID number as the other files, and append '*_header*' to the filename. It should now show up in Steam.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm SUPER late to the question but I've finally managed to make this work and I don't want anybody else to suffer as I did.

What you want to do is use a tool called [steamgrid](https://github.com/boppreh/steamgrid). It's on GitHub. Instructions on how to use it are available on the GitHub page; however in short you have to extract [the zip file that you have installed](https://github.com/boppreh/steamgrid/releases/) somewhere (doesn't matter where), copy your cover image into the `games` folder as `GAMENAME.banner.png`, run the tool through the command line (`steamgrid -nonsteamonly` if you only want non-Steam games to be affected) and let it do its magic. And, of course, restart Steam once it's done. **This will apply a custom banner to the game's Big Picture Mode box **without changing its original icon**.**

It turns out that Steam Big Picture Mode uses a *really* fancy file naming convention for its banners, so the easiest and fastest way to apply them is to use this tool. It also works for icons, logos, grids and library page backgrounds and can apply overlays over existing games so I'd recommend checking it out.

Really hope this helps, I personally spent 2 days trying to figure out how to do this and I hope you didn't have to go through what I've gone through.